# Return true from query when all values are 0

Tags: sql

I have this

```
id   number  stock
1    555     1
2    555     0
3    444     0
```

I want to return true when all the values are 0 on the same number.
Number 555 is false, because there is 1 on stock. Number 3 is true because there are all stock values 0.

How can i do this?

Comment: Is number indexed? Is id the primary key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
select 
  number,
  case
    when min(stock) = 0 and max(stock) = 0 then 'true'
    else 'false'
  end as TrueOrFalse
from TheTable
group by number
```

The query will return all distinct values in the `number` column, along with the corresponding true/false status.

Here's a live demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61c82/1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display indicator for all the rows then try this

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Count(CASE WHEN stock = 0 THEN 1 END)OVER(partition BY number) f_count,
                Count(1)OVER(partition BY number) AS t_count,*
         FROM   Yourtable)
SELECT id,
       number,
       stock,
       Indicator=CASE WHEN f_count <> t_count THEN 'False' ELSE 'True' END
FROM   cte
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/022c6/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT number,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN stock <> 0 THEN 1 END) = 0 
       THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END
FROM dbo.TableName
GROUP BY number
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b3bbd/2/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
select number,stock,
    case when sum(stock)=0 then 'true' else 'false' end AS Staus  
    from #temp group by number,stock
```